# Laravel Livewire: Jquery doesn't work in a livewire component

Tags: jquery, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

## I can use jquery in my view, but not in my livewire component.

**This is my livewire component where i want to use Jquery:** \resources\views\livewire\search.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1 id="id">Test</h1>
    <script>
        $('#id').css("background-color", "red");;
    </script>
</div>
```

**This is my view:** \resources\views\components\sections\search.blade.php

```
@livewire('forms.search')
```

**This is my app.js:** \resources\js\app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
```

### output: Test

### But if i do everything in the view like:

\resources\views\components\sections\search.blade.php

```
<h1 id="id">Test</h1>
<script>
    $('#id').css("background-color", "red");;
</script>
```

### output: Test (with red background)

Answer (score 3):

There are two options for this. you can do it first by giving wire:ignore to the parent tag of the livewire blade. and the second option :

Add this code inside Livewire's render function

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('jquery');
```

and then run it like this

```
window.addEventListener('jquery', event => {
        $('#id').css("background-color", "red");;
    });
```

Additionally, make sure to run this command

```
npm run watch
```

After that, make sure to include the public/js/app.js file in the blade file

and

```
@livewireScripts
</body>
```

Make sure the code is written

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jquery js file from cdn, into your "app.blade.php" file.
Like this:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" ...
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery must added first then used, so in component you can't use this way because component in the middle of page, but you can use with DOMContentLoaded event like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 $('#id').css("background-color", "red");
})
</script>
```

if you want run this script by each render, you must use livewire events, for example this below run the script in each update that livewire make:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

   Livewire.hook('element.updated', (el, component) => {
      $('#id').css("background-color", "red");;
   })

});
```

of course in this example you can't see the result difference.

see all livewire's hooks in their site: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks#js-hooks

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found the solution

Use the following code for your css update:

```
<script>
    $(document).find('#id').css("background-color", "red");
</script>
```